# .Net Core localization, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, localization

I am playing with .Net core and localization. I have followed a couple of articles, chiefly https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization but can't seem to get data from my resource file.

**Startup.ConfigureServices**

```
   services.AddLocalization(opts => opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
            opts =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
                };

                opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB");
                // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
                opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                // UI strings that we have localized.
                opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });

        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(opts => { opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(); })
            .AddViewLocalization(
                LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                opts => opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
            .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
```

**A ViewModel I would Like to be localized**

```
[Validator(typeof(LoginViewModelValidator))]
public class Login
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class LoginViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Login>
{
    public LoginViewModelValidator(IStringLocalizer<LoginViewModelValidator> localizer)
    {
        RuleFor(login => login.Email).NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage(x => localizer["Email"])
            .EmailAddress()
            .WithMessage(x => localizer["Email address must be valid"]);
        RuleFor(reg => reg.Password).NotEmpty().WithMessage(x => localizer["Password required"]);
    }
}
```

**Location of resource file**

[image: Location of Resource file]

**Resource file contents**

[image: Resource file contents]

As far as I can tell the localizer should be able to find the localized string, as my current culture is en-GB.

Does anyone know what i have done wrong.

I am also confused as the msdn article explains

> If the localized value of "About Title" is not found, then the indexer
>   key is returned, that is, the string "About Title".

but how can it ever lookup using "About Title" as a name as it has a space in it and cannot be entered into the .resx name?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have removed the culture configuration from IServicesCollection and added it to the middlewrae pipeline instead:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
            };

            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB"),
                // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                // UI strings that we have localized.
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Auth}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

I also enusured the naming of the resource was correct. IE Full namespace, minus the assembly name then classname then culture.

ViewModels.LoginViewModelValidator.en-GB.resx and it all works now. Thanks for the comments everyone

Comment: _as it has a space in it and cannot be entered into the .resx name?_ This is non-sense. The Resource Editor within VS 2017 will show it as an error if you have spaces or other special characters in there, but it will compile, run and resolve normally. The space thing is probably because of the classic way resources were used and about the generated compile/design time constants

Comment: Thanks I didn't realise that. Regardless though it is unable to find my resource, is there anything obviously wrong with my approach?

Comment: Dunno, had similar issue under windows, where my created resource had a lower-case `de-de` rather then the `de-DE` defined within Startup.cs and it wouldn't pick that up. So maybe check the spelling on the file system (not the display name in project view). Also make sure your namespaces are correct, i.e. is your ViewModelValidator located in ViewModel namespace (which would be odd naming convention)

Comment: From docs: _If your **targeted class's namespace is not the same as the assembly** name you will need **the full type name**. For example, in the sample project a resource for the type ExtraNamespace.Tools would be named ExtraNamespace.Tools.fr.resx._

Comment: thanks Tseng, after your clue above about namespaces I re-read the article and found that. I'm gonna make some changes now.

Comment: Post your Middleware pipeline, all localization middleware should be BEFORE the MVC middleware

Comment: That was the issue, I was setting all the culture stuff into IServiceCollection rather than the actual IApplicationBuilder. School boy error!

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need this in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

Did you wire up the RequestLocalization middleware in Configure?

```
var locOptions = 
app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
```

I am not sure about the sub folders you have under the Resources folder I am not doing that in my projects and it is working for me.